# Radio Button and associated Label not aligned

Tags: html, css, radio-button, label

Radio buttons are showing like the attached image. How to align the Label and the button.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
    width: 18px;
    min-width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="myRadios1" id="myRadios1" value="Yes" ONCLICK="show_info_block(this.value)" />Yes</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="myRadios2" id="myRadios2" value="No" ONCLICK="show_info_block(this.value)" />No</label>
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Please add more detail, how you want it to be, currently it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 solutions but i think one of them is better:

1. first Dont wrap you `<input>` in `<label>` and do this instead:

   {label}
2. then for css :

   .label-container {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   }

   input[type='radio'] {
   margin: auto;
   }

you can use display flex and align-items: center for each label with your own code
but I think it's not clean at all.